# Is DrawableCompat.setTint() lazy?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-drawable

I am designing an app that has 3 button in main activity, and several buttons in a fragment. I want to change the color of a button in the fragment, depending on which button of main activity is toggled.

```
color1.setOnClickListener {
        brush_chosen = 1

        color1.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black)
        color2.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000)
        color3.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000)
        if (frag_num == 8 ){
            frag_8p.set_frag_value(frag_num,brush_chosen)
        }
        
    }
```

The function set_frag_value is :

```
fun set_frag_value(frag_num:Int,brush:Int) : Int
{
    brush_chosen=brush
    return brush
}
```

This change the value of **brush_chosen**. Then I made a function :

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    ib0.setOnClickListener { view ->
        Log.d("brush_color","Brush of 0 : "+brush_chosen)
        if (brush_chosen==1)
        {
            Log.d("brush_color","Brush Confirm : "+brush_chosen)
            DrawableCompat.setTint(ib0.drawable, ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(),R.color.rndcolor1))
        }
        else if (brush_chosen==2)
        {
            Log.d("brush_color","Brush Confirm : "+brush_chosen)
            DrawableCompat.setTint(ib0.drawable, ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(),R.color.purple_500))
        }
        else if (brush_chosen==3)
        {
            Log.d("brush_color","Brush Confirm : "+brush_chosen)
            DrawableCompat.setTint(ib0.drawable, ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(),R.color.teal_200))
        }
        Log.d("brush_color","End of onclicklistener ")

    }
}
```

I checked the log and theoretically this code should work correctly. However, I found that the button color did not change properly, even I checked my app prints all log correctly. For example, when I clicked button color1 in main activity, variable brush_chosen becomes 1 and the first button in fragment I clicked changes its color. But **the second button I clicked does not change its color**.

Is there any problem on my code using DrawableCompat ??

Answer (score 1):

Android does some `Drawable` state caching under the hood. You might need to call `mutate()` on the `Drawable` you want to tint and then set the new `Drawable` in order for the tint to show up properly.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use mutate() ? I am now having difficulty on adjusting your advice since I have no idea how to .